# Connection String for reading an XML File test data for Data Driven Unit Testing

Tags: xml

I've an XML Data file containing test data for data driven unit testing. Now I want add a connection string and a data source in Unit Test project. I had tried following connection string but it didn't work.

```
<add name="MyXMLConn" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\XMLData.xml;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

Can any one help me in this regards?

Comment: what was the error you received

Comment: How do you use this connection string? Which technology do you use? .net? java? something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but could it be the semicolon `;` at the end of your connection string?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this :-

"<"add name="MyXML" connectionString="|DataDirectory|\\xmlFileName.xml" providerName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML"/>

remove double quotes before add

and add this lines above Test Method

[DeploymentItem(@"..\..\Data.xml")] //I put the .xml file to the root of the test project
[DataSource("MyXMLDataSource")]

I hope it helps